# How to add a custom cli schema in existing project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a custom angular-cli command to my project.
My goal is to be able to run custom command in my project, like: `ng g table --params.`
The schema was created successfully, but i don't know where is the right way to place it in the project.
The only way i found is to add the schema to @schematics node_model, which is not good way as well.
Another way to do that is to create a new project for the schema, and use npm-link to link the schema to the project, but this is bad solution.

thanks.